# mod_rewrite rule and setenv

Tags: mod-rewrite, setenv

Is there anyway to use the value set in a `SetEnv` on the `RewriteRule` statement?

Example:

```
SetEnv MY_SCRIPT myScript.php

rewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{MY_SCRIPT} [L]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/env.html the SetEnv is called **after** the RewriteRule. Therefore it seems to be impossible to use any variable set via SetEnv in a RewriteRule- or RewriteCond-statement.

Using SetEnvIf on the other hand is called **before** the RewriteRule and therefore Variables set there can be used in a RewriteRule- or RewriteCond-statement.

So something like the following should work:

```
SetEnvIf SERVER_PROTOCOL "HTTP.*" MY_SCRIPT=myScript.php
rewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{ENV:MY_SCRIPT} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%{ENV:MY_SCRIPT}` instead of `%{MY_SCRIPT}`.